# Cordova notifications not working for Android

Tags: cordova, notifications, ionic3, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I have updated the cordova plugins in my project in Ionic 3, and I have lost the notifications in Android (version 8.0.0) and iOS 11 devices. However I can see the notifications  in the browser (Chrome). I want to use local-notifications for fix this. I'm using the plugin via Ionic Native wrapper.

These are my plugins in the package.json:

```
"plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {},
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {}
    }
```

Also  in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.6.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "1.2.1",
    "cordova": "9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "3.0.1",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notifications": "1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "4.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.7",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "4.2.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
```

Could be any kind of incompatiblity? Should I change any version number to have notification?

The versions of the plugin are:

```
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 4.2.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the versions of the installed Cordova plugins? Do you refer to push notifications or local notifications? How are you using the corresponding plugin (via plugin API or Ionic Native wrapper)? That information would help better understand the question (you can edit it)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see any Cordova plugin related to notifications. It would be helpful if you could prepare a minimal Cordova / Ionic project which reproduces the issue, and link it here

Comment: In the package.json I have also the dependencies: @ionic-native/local-notifications": "4.6.0" and cordova-plugin-local-notifications": "1.0.0"

Comment: Ok, now I can see them. Would you mind posting a minimal Cordova / Ionic project which reproduces the issue?

Comment: Maybe it's related to https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1820